# Update file directory across whole file automatically

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

on the wordpress site I am working on, my page templates have lots of html, all I need to do is figure out a way automatically update the links in the html and CSS, with the new file path, so everything loads and I don't have to individually change each link Ive been trying to figure it out, and I feel like if requires a script that get_template_directory_uri() to all links when the page loads What I need is someone to write a script or some php what will update the file directories of all my images and files etc, so that when the page loads it doesnt load broken

is there a way to automatically apply get_template_directory_uri() to all the links when the page loads

Comment: Show a simple example of what you are referring to , it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: throughout my html i have links to js and images like these

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="images/39.png">

there are lot of different ones scattered through the html, and for them to load, i now need to add the file path 
wp-content/themes/theme/ 
in front of them so they look like this 
wp-content/themes/theme/images/39.jpg 

I could go and change them all manually, but, it takes a long time, and I feel like there is a way to write code that will automatically apply something like get_template_directory_uri() to the front so they load

Comment: I don't know that there is a way with without doing some sort of DOM parsing or a JavaScript to do that. I think if I were doing it, I would probably do a site-wide (which ever directory these files are in) find and replace with whatever coding app you use. Then just use the `get_template_directory_uri()` function going forward. There may be some server trick, but on a hardcoded url, that might not be possible. Just because I have never heard of it, doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exist!